# Rails - how to change <select> to be just a hidden field when called with an id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, html-select

I have a form with a `<select>` element for the Group.

[image]

[The application stores bookmark links and groups for them]

When doing a 'new', everything work correctly.  The new form works, the `<select>` dropdown has the list of groups and has their ID's.

The problem now is that I want to call the 'new link' from a *different* place that will *already know the group*.  In this case I don't want an option to select the group, I just want to use the group id passed to it.

The form itself has:

```
= f.select :group_id, @groups
```

My routes include:

```
  resources :groups do
    resources :links # Added so that I can do group/:id/link/new ...
    collection do
      post 'order_links'
    end 
  end 
  match 'search' => 'links#index'
  match 'advanced_search' => 'links#advanced_search'
  resources :links do
    collection do
      get 'groups'
    end 
  end
```

The controller that's showing the form for this "new link" has:

```
  def new
    @link = Link.new
    @groups = Group.all.collect { |g| [g.group_name, g.id] }
    @group_name =
      if params[:group_id]
        'for the '+Group.find(params[:group_id]).group_name + ' group.'
      else
        ''
      end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

I tried changing the view to have this:

```
-if params[:group_id]
  = f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => params[:group_id]
-else
= f.select :group_id, @groups
```

but it didn't work, I still got the `<select>` element, defaulting to its first `<option>`.

I actually had this working as some point in the past but has broken since, so hopefully I'm fairly close.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation in your HAML template is wrong. It should be:

```
 - if params[:group_id]
   = f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => params[:group_id]
 - else
   = f.select :group_id, @groups
```

(If that was just the way it came out when you entered the question, I will delete this answer.)